# React - Contents won't load until refresh - state management issue

Tags: reactjs, state, react-18

Data won't load until I refresh the page. I believe the issue is state management but I can't seem to make it work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

When a user signs up for an account, they log into the session and all users posts are supposed to be rendered. However, in my case, it's not rendering until I refresh the page.

client/src/context/ContentContext.js

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ErrorContext } from "./ErrorContext";

const ContentContext = createContext({});
const ContentProvider = ({children}) => {
    const { setErrors } = useContext(ErrorContext);
    const [contents, setContents] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/posts')
        .then(resp => {
            if (resp.ok) {
                resp.json().then(data => {
                    setContents(data);
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(errors => {
            setErrors(errors);
        });
    }, [setErrors])

    const addPost = (newPost) => {
        setContents([...contents, newPost]);
    }

    const editPost = (newPost) => {
        const updatedContentList = contents.map(post => {
            if (newPost.id === post.id) {
                return newPost
            } else {
                return post;
            }
        });
        setContents(updatedContentList);
    }

    const deletePost = (id) => {
        const updatedContentList = contents.filter(post => post.id !== id)
        setContents(updatedContentList);
    }

    return (
        <ContentContext.Provider value={{ contents, addPost, editPost, deletePost }}>{children}</ContentContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { ContentContext, ContentProvider }
```

client/src/posts/PostDetail.js

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

function PostDetail () {
    const { setErrors } = useContext(ErrorContext);
    const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
    const { contents, deletePost } = useContext(ContentContext);
    const postId = parseInt(useParams().id);
    const post = contents.find(post => post.id === postId);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`/posts/${post.id}/likes`)
           .then(resp => resp.json())
           .then(data => {
               setLiked(data.liked);
           })
           .catch(error => {
               setErrors(error)
           })
         }, [post.id, setErrors])
     }

export default PostDetail;
```

Comment: I don't see anything related to login or session here

Answer (score 0):

i think that should be okey :

```
 import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ErrorContext } from "./ErrorContext";
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthContext"; 

const ContentProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { setErrors } = useContext(ErrorContext);
  const { isLoggedIn } = useContext(AuthContext); 
  const [contents, setContents] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); 

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      fetch('/posts')
        .then((resp) => {
          if (resp.ok) {
            resp.json().then((data) => {
              setContents(data);
              setLoading(false); 
            });
          } else {
            setLoading(false); 
            setErrors("Err");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setLoading(false); 
          setErrors(error);
        });
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn, setErrors]);

  return (
    <ContentContext.Provider value={{ contents, setLoading }}>
      {loading ? <p>Loading...</p> : children}
    </ContentContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { ContentProvider };
```

Comment: This will rerender each component that is wrapped inside this provider. Not a best practice to follow. It'll cause issues with performance.

Answer (score 0):

File: client/src/posts/PostDetail.js

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

function PostDetail() {
  const { setErrors } = useContext(ErrorContext);
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  const { contents, deletePost } = useContext(ContentContext);
  const [post, setPost] = useState({});
  const postId = parseInt(useParams().id);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (contents?.length) {
      const content = contents.find((c) => c.id === postId);
      setPost(content);
    }
  }, [contents]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/posts/${post.id}/likes`)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setLiked(data.liked);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setErrors(error);
      });
  }, [post.id, setErrors]);
}

export default PostDetail;
```

Try this code And let me know if it helps.